# You have attempted to set a value of type class entity

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am using jpa 2 with eclipslink...

I am trying to execute this query:

List postEntityList = entityManager.createQuery("select p from PostEntity p where p.organizationEntity=?1 and p.organizationUnitEntity=?2 and p.organizationLocationEntity=?3 and p.organizationBatchEntity=?4 and p.postCategoryEntity=?5 and p.dateOfPosting between ?6 and ?7 order by p.rating desc").setParameter(1, organizationEntity).setParameter(2, organizationUnitEntity).setParameter(3, organizationLocationEntity).setParameter(4, organizationBatchEntity).setParameter(5, postCategoryEntity).setParameter(6, minimumTime).setParameter(7, maximumTime).getResultList();

But I am getting the error:

You have attempted to set a value of type class entity.PostCategoryEntity for parameter 5 with expected type of class entity.OrganizationEntity from query string select p from PostEntity p where p.organizationEntity=?1 and p.organizationUnitEntity=?2 and p.organizationLocationEntity=?3 and p.organizationBatchEntity=?4 and p.postCategoryEntity=?5 and p.dateOfPosting between ?6 and ?7 order by p.rating desc.

Why is it so!!! Any idea...??

Comment: What if you use named parameters instead of indexed?  Could be a starts with 0 vs 1 issue.

Comment: I have tried to use named parameters but still the error is same. I am using eclipselink 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

The class of parameter5 should be entity.

Maybe your parameter5 is a FK, if it is, you need to use parameter5.parameter to find the real variable.